# Schema error from postgresql update statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a POSTGRESQL update statement that I'm trying to rewrite with explicit joins and needing some help whereby the NESTED select statement alias is recognized to execute the outer UPDATE statement.  Not sure why the "se" alias for the nested select is NOT recognized.  I know I must be missing something basic.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Error I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  schema "se" does not exist

********** Error **********

ERROR: schema "se" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
```

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE students
SET custom_400011449 = CAST(cfso1.label as integer)+1,
       custom_400011770 = 761 --'2016-2017' 
FROM (
       SELECT se2.student_id, cfso1.id, cfso1.label
       FROM students s
       INNER JOIN student_enrollment se2
       ON s.student_id = se2.student_id
       INNER JOIN school_gradelevels sg
       ON se2.grade_id = sg.id
       INNER JOIN custom_field_log_entries sle
       ON se2.student_id = sle.source_id
       LEFT JOIN custom_field_select_options cfso1 
       ON s.custom_400011449 = cfso1.id
       LEFT JOIN custom_field_select_options cfso2
       ON s.custom_400011770 = cfso2.id
       LEFT JOIN custom_field_select_options cfso3
       ON sle.log_field4::INT = cfso3.id
       WHERE se2.syear =2016
       AND s.custom_400011449 IS NOT NULL
       AND s.custom_400011898 IS NULL 
       AND s.custom_400011899 IS NULL
       AND sle.field_id = 15 --400010549 
       AND sle.log_field2 IS NULL 
       AND cfso2.label = '2015-2016'
       AND cfso3.label IN ('LE', 'NL-F', 'NL-S') 
       AND sg.short_name BETWEEN '01' AND '12' 
       AND (
              SELECT COUNT(school_date) 
              FROM student_enrollment se
              INNER JOIN attendance_calendar ac 
              ON se.calendar_id = ac.calendar_id
              WHERE se.student_id = se2.student_id
              AND se.syear =2016 --{SYEAR}
              AND ac.syear =2016 --{SYEAR}
              AND ac.school_date >= se.start_date 
              AND ac.school_date <= NOW() 
              AND (se.end_date IS NULL OR ac.school_date <= se.end_date) 
              AND se.custom_9 IS NULL 
              AND se2.start_date >= '2016-08-22' 
              GROUP BY se.student_id 
              HAVING COUNT(ac.school_date) >= 59) 
       >= 59) AS se
LEFT JOIN custom_field_select_options cfso1
ON se.cfso1.id = cfso1.id
WHERE students.student_id = se.student_id
```

Comment: if you share DDL and several DMLs to build your schema, it would be easier. your query is bigger then tiny

Comment: You use alias "se" inside the most nested select and also for marking higher nested select. It is possible planner rearranges query in some way and is confused by this. try to use different alias in most nested select - not "se"

Comment: Hi guys,  thanks for the responses.  I found my problem whereby I had a syntax error in ON condition "se.cfso1.id".  Once I cleared that up the problem was resolved.  I just could not see it until I got away from it. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem whereby I had a syntax error in the ON condition "se.cfso1.id". Once I cleared that up the problem was resolved.